# Why do we have to use pre-image in the formal definition of random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, definition

There is this definition of random variable:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}), (\Omega',\mathcal{F}')$ be two event spaces. We say that a function $X:\Omega\to\Omega'$ is a random variable from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ to $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}')$ if $\forall$ $A'\in\mathcal{F}'$, we have $X^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{F}$.

My question is why do we have to use preimage in the definition? What if we change it to $\forall$ $A\in\mathcal{F}$ then $X(A)\in\mathcal{F}'$?

Could anyone please provide some explanations and if possible some counterexamples on what would go wrong if we don't use the preimage in the definition?

Thanks.

Comment: Commonly a probability measure $P$ is added to $\langle\Omega,\mathcal F\rangle$. Then sets like $\{X\in A\}:=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in A\}=X^{-1}(A)$ can be "measured" if they belong to $\mathcal F$. That is what we want, and it falls away if use your proposed definition of random variable.

Comment: @drhab. Can you clarify and explain a bit more on what do you mean by "falls away"? Thanks.

Comment: Let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be a r.v. and ask yourself the question: what is the probability that $X<1$? You can only answer that if $X^{−1}(−\infty,1)$ can be measured. In "your" definition there is no guarantee that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Let me complement on the answer given by drhab.

Indeed, one would not be able in general to compute the measure of the set $X^{-1}A$. However, there is really no problem to introduce **another** notion of "random variable" by requiring that the image of a measurable set is a measurable set and proceed from there. Something similar (a bit peculiar though, from the point of view of dynamics) is done from time to time in the topological category, with the notion of a "proper map".

On the other hand, there would be serious problems in order to consider stationary probability measures since you would only be able to consider random variables that were invertible mod zero. From my point of view, this is the main reason why one should prefer the usual definition.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by invertible mod zero. Could you explain that please? Thanks.

Comment: "invertible mod zero" means invertible after discarding sets of measure zero.